# How to generate an alphabetic incremental string?

Tags: php

For example
I'm looking for a function that keeps incrementing letters
Starts wit "aaaaaa" and goes to "aaaaab" and ends with "zzzzzz"

Comment: This looks a lot like an implementation request :) Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Won't this bring your server down? Its quite a huge loop with 6 character string having 26 possibilities for each slot

Comment: @Ø Hanky Panky Ø - nope, it'll just take a little while to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's ability to [increment characters Perl style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

```
$char = 'aaaaaa';
$endChar = 'zzzzzz';
$endChar++;
while ($char != $endChar) {
    echo $char++, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use increment operator

```
$start = "aaaaaa";
$end = "zzzzzz";

while($start ++ != $end) {
    // print after every 10,000,000 million
    (@$i ++ % 10000000 == 0) and print($start . PHP_EOL);
}

echo "Total  ", number_format($i, 0);
```

Output

```
aaaaab
avwyxl
brtxuv
cnqwsf
djnvpp
efkumz
fbhtkj
fxesht
gtbrfd
hoyqcn
ikvozx
jgsnxh
kcpmur
kymlsb
lujkpl
mqgjmv
nmdikf
oiahhp
pdxgez
pzufcj
qvrdzt
rrocxd
snlbun
tjiarx
ufezph
vbbymr
vwyxkb
wsvwhl
xosvev
ykpucf
zgmszp

Total 308,915,775
```

Comment: Be very careful when using `<` or `>` comparators with characters, because the comparison will be alphabetic. I always prefer taking the end value, incrementing that, then using `!=`